# Content Provider Like Jabbr

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Basic idea is if i add url from you tube to my chat it would get the content from youtube and display the video on chat window itself.

How can i get the Content Provider like [Jabbr](https://jabbr.net/) or even like gmail or Facebook. is there a known JS library or standard function to accomplish this?
i looked at the Jabbr code , it has been done on the server side and does not work doing page refresh.

I am looking for any resources that you can point me to that can help me to get started.
i am looking to add different content provider like Youtube.com, twitter etc. to my chat.

Comment: When you find the answer, I'll use it in jabbr :)

Comment: looks like i will have to write my own JS

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found any pre-made library to do this either. But it's not too bad to roll your own; jQuery code to automatically inject a YouTube video might look like this:

```
urls = text.match(/http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?.*v\=([^\?\&]+)/);

if (urls) {
    $("#chatbox").prepend('<div class="entry"><iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="320" height="240" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + urls[1] + '" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe></div>');
    return;
}
```

Check out this example fiddle which demonstrates the effect: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pDgTj/13/).  It also matches plain links as another example. To extend this concept, you just need to figure out what kinds of input you want to match (e.g. a regular expression as in my examples), and what code you need to inject (e.g. the YouTube embed iframe).

You should take care to carefully test your expressions and injections lest you allow users to inject malicious code.

Comment: Since he mentions asp.net mvc, he may be better off letting the server handle parsing urls. Just passing in the value to the System.Uri class would be enough to at least determine whether or not a string is a valid url. He'd also be able to quickly strip out XSS and other stuff, or even ban certain links all together.